# Deploy ASP.net APP to azure web app without source code

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've a dedicated machine with at least 6 diferent asp.net 4.5 applications where the developer deployed compiled versions. This apps are all working fine now, but I haven't access to source code.

Now I want to deploy this apps to Azure, but not to a VM, to an Azure Web App Service. Is it posible?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite possibly. We can't say for sure without more information.

You'll need to FTP all files from your existing root directory/directories to your new Web App. If it's a vanilla ASP.NET web app and there aren't any dependent issues (such as databases on other servers that you cannot move or poke holes through firewalls), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many considerations. For instance, if the applications have dependencies on specific drive letters, you won't be able to mount those drives.

This is just one example, you can take a look at the restrictions that are imposed on Web Apps: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

The best way to know, is to create a new site, deploy the files, and see what breaks.